# Lead Source Gone after converting "Lead" to "Contact"

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, convert

I am having some trouble keeping the lead source. For some odd reason when I am converting a lead into a Contact/Account the lead source that originally came with the lead seems to disappear. Then I have to re input the lead source manually. Is there a way that I can keep this from happening? I would like the lead source to stay the same when converting the lead to a Contact and also when creating a new opportunity related to that account.

Answer (score 2):

After conversion of Lead, the Lead Source of Contact, Opportunity will be by default same as of Lead.

I think, there must be some trigger or workflow or other processes running during lead conversion or Contact/Opportunity creation which is changing the Lead Source to a different value.

Comment: What about mapping the lead "lead source" to the "lead source" in the opportunities object. Do you think that would work?

Comment: That should work, Standard Lead fields will automatically to mapped with Account, Contact and Opportunities. Please refer this link for Out-of-box mapping https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm&language=en

Comment: If you have custom fields in Lead those can be mapped upon clicking on "Map Lead Fields" button in Lead's field section. You can put a debug log during lead conversion process to know how processes are creating/updating records

Comment: @Alias311 can you close this question